# C# Facebook SDK Access Token Handling

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I found C# Facebook SDK http://csharpsdk.org/ (not sure Official or not).
I want to use graph api search function using C#, I need access Access Token to use graph api, question is can I store access token parmanent as long as I have access to facebook app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible anymore. It was possible with Offline access permission. But this is a permission that is or will be removed by faceboob. See the facebook information site for more information.